# Apps Script Trigger not running the same as running code within the Editor

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, triggers

This code has run fine for months, and I haven't made any recent changes to it. The basics is that it loops through my team members emails, and sends them each a summary of some information. But now, it has been sending them multiple emails, and the wrong info, as if there is some issue with the loop??

It's alot of code, but I figured I better include it all here, I am just taking out some contact info:

```
     var st1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1en0zmKvFthJpS_0eVDFGsvEuwq3uGhHZ53b34LF9D5g').getSheetByName("QCA+ Props")
    var today1 = new Date()
    var weekday1 = today1.getDay()
    var monthday1 = Utilities.formatDate(today1, "GMT-7", "d")
    var BMs = []
    var BMEmails = []
    var j=0
    var i=0
 
 
 
 function sendRundownSum() {

   st1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1en0zmKvFthJpS_0eVDFGsvEuwq3uGhHZ53b34LF9D5g').getSheetByName("Daily Email Template")

   Logger.log(weekday1 + "   " + today1)
   
   for(j=0; j<BMs.length; j++) {
   if(weekday1 < 6 && weekday1 > 0) {
     if(monthday1<20) {
   line1 =[];
   line2 =[];

   SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   st1.getRange(2,2).setValue(BMs[j])
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   if(st1.getRange(7,3).getValue() !== "") {
     Logger.log('lates')
  
   line1.push("Please choose late type in column L:")
   line1.push(st1.getRange(7,3).getValue())

   line1.push("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1en0zmKvFthJpS_0eVDFGsvEuwq3uGhHZ53b34LF9D5g/edit#gid=1954247434&fvid=344012085")
   line1.push("\n")
   line1 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line1).join('\n')
   }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

   if(st1.getRange(9,3).getValue() !== "") {
     Logger.log('action items')
     //line2.push("\n")
   line2.push("Items needing action today: ")
   line2.push(st1.getRange(9,3).getValue())
   for(i=14; i<100; i++) {
   if(st1.getRange(i,3).getValue() !== "") {
   line2.push(st1.getRange(i,3).getValue())
   }
   }
   line2 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line2).join('\n')
   }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   var line0 = [];
  if(st1.getRange(8,3).getValue() !== ""){
    Logger.log('exports')
   //line0.push("\n") 
   line0.push("Properties QC Approved and not Exported:")
   line0.push(st1.getRange(8,3).getValue())
   line0.push("\n")
   line0 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line0).join('\n')
  }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
     var line3 = [];
  if(st1.getRange(10,3).getValue() !== ""){
    Logger.log('goal dates')
   //line3.push("\n") 
   line3.push("Props without Goal Date:")
   line3.push(st1.getRange(10,3).getValue())
   line3.push("\n")
   line3 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line3).join('\n')
  }
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var line4 = [];
  if(st1.getRange(11,3).getValue() !== ""){
    Logger.log('autoproof')
   //line4.push("\n") 
   line4.push("Props not on Autoproof:")
   line4.push(st1.getRange(11,3).getValue())
   line4.push("\n")
   line4 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line4).join('\n')
  }


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var line5 = [];
  if(st1.getRange(12,3).getValue() !== ""){
    Logger.log('prebill')
   //line5.push("\n") 
   line5.push("Props Binned, Prebill not Sent:")
   line5.push(st1.getRange(12,3).getValue())
   line5.push("\n")
   line5 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line5).join('\n')
  }



  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    var line6 = [];
  if(st1.getRange(13,3).getValue() !== ""){
    Logger.log('coming up')
   //line6.push("\n") 
   line6.push("" + st1.getRange(3,3).getValue() + " - props coming up:")
   line6.push(st1.getRange(13,3).getValue())
   line6.push("\n")
   line6 = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], line6).join('\n')
  }


  SpreadsheetApp.flush();

   //if(st1.getRange(5,5).getValue() !== "" || (st1.getRange(5,1).getValue() !== ""|| st1.getRange(2,4).getValue() !== "")) {

     if((line1  + line0 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6) !== "") {

    htmlBody = "Hello!\n\n"  + line1  + line0 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6 + line2;
  

   }
   else

   {
   htmlBody = "Hello!" + "\n" + "\n" + "No URGENT items for today!"

   } 

    recipient =  BMEmails[j] ;
 

    subject = "Rundown Summary: " + BMs[j];

  

   MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, htmlBody);
   Logger.log("Email Sent for " + BMs[j])

   }
   }
   }
   }
```

Even now when I run this manually (in the editor) it works as expected, but when I let the trigger run, which is time based, and once a day it seems like something with the loop is breaking

Comment: Does your log of you running it manually match the log of it running automatically?

Comment: I actually don't know how to check the auto log

Comment: Try using Logger.log

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sendRundownSum() {
  var dt = new Date()
  var wd = dt.getDay()
  var date = dt.getDate()
  var BMs = [];//don't see how these get initialized
  var BMEmails = [];//dont't see how these get intialized
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1en0zmKvFthJpS_0eVDFGsvEuwq3uGhHZ53b34LF9D5g');
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Daily Email Template");
  for (let j = 0; j < BMs.length; j++) {
    if (wd < 6 && wd > 0) {
      if (date < 20) {
        let line1 = [];
        let line2 = [];
        sh1.getRange(2, 2).setValue(BMs[j])
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        let v = sh1.getRange(1, 3, 14).getValues().flat();
        v.unshift("");
        if (v[7] !== "") {
          Logger.log('lates');
          line1.push("Please choose late type in column L:");
          line1.push(v[7]);
          line1.push("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1en0zmKvFthJpS_0eVDFGsvEuwq3uGhHZ53b34LF9D5g/edit#gid=1954247434&fvid=344012085");
          line1.push("\n")
          let line1 = line1.join('\n');
        }
        if (v[9] !== "") {
          Logger.log('action items');
          line2.push("Items needing action today: ");
          line2.push(v[9]);
          let l2 = sh2.getRange(14,3, 87).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
          let line2 = l2.join('\n');
        }
        let line0 = [];
        if (v[8] !== "") {
          line0.push("Properties QC Approved and not Exported:");
          line0.push(v[8]);
          line0.push("\n");
          let line0 = line0.join('\n');
        }
        let line3 = [];
        if (v[10] !== "") {
          Logger.log('goal dates')
          line3.push("Props without Goal Date:")
          line3.push(v10)
          line3.push("\n")
          let line3 = line3.join('\n')
        }
        let line4 = [];
        if (v[11] !== "") {
          Logger.log('autoproof')
          line4.push("Props not on Autoproof:")
          line4.push(v[11])
          line4.push("\n")
          let line4 = line4.join('\n')
        }
        let line5 = [];
        if (v[12] !== "") {
          Logger.log('prebill')
          line5.push("Props Binned, Prebill not Sent:")
          line5.push(v[12])
          line5.push("\n")
          let line5 = line5.join('\n')
        }
        let line6 = [];
        if (v[13] !== "") {
          Logger.log('coming up')
          line6.push("" + sh1.getRange(3, 3).getValue() + " - props coming up:")
          line6.push(v[13])
          line6.push("\n")
          line6 = line6.join('\n')
        }
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        if ((line1 + line0 + line2 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6) !== "") {
          htmlBody = "Hello!\n\n" + line1 + line0 + line3 + line4 + line5 + line6 + line2;
        }
        else {
          htmlBody = "Hello!" + "\n" + "\n" + "No URGENT items for today!"
        }
        recipient = BMEmails[j].join(",");
        subject = "Rundown Summary: " + BMs[j];
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, htmlBody);
        Logger.log("Email Sent for " + BMs[j])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'line0' before initialization

Comment: Try moving the initialization